# Template Overriding Opencart

Tags: templates, opencart

I have developed a **module** that lets *admin* to select **template** for a *specified date*. But i have no idea how I can *override* the **template** automatically in the *front-end*. Help me out with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to change the "config_template" value to the new on

```
$this->config->set('config_template', $new_value);
```

Comment: well this sets the system configuration to new template but doesn't retrieve the previous one after that specific date . .

Comment: incorrect, this sets it for the duration of the script, so you would need to add this in the catalog side and alter it once all of the config has been loaded